# NullPointerException trying to access EJB in JAX-RS controller

Tags: jakarta-ee, nullpointerexception, ejb, jax-rs

I have a EE app and now Im trying to use jax rs project that use a ejb method from the EE app.

When I access the url `http://localhost:8080/rest/projectws/getplayers` I get:

```
Servlet Path:
/rest

Path Info:
/projectws/getplayers

Query String:
null

Stack Trace
org.jboss.resteasy.spi.UnhandledException: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

I will put below the code that I think that should be relevant for this issue.

I have a **interface** "PlayerLocal.java" to return players from a team:

```
@Local
public interface PlayerLocal{
    public ArrayList<String> getFromTeam(String teamName);
}
```

Than in "Player.java" I have:

```
   @Stateless
    public class Player implements PlayerLocal{
    @Override
        public ArrayList<String> getFromTeam(String teamName) {
            ArrayList<String> result;
            List<Player> players;

            Query q=em.createNamedQuery("Team.findByName",Team.class);
            q.setParameter("c", teamName);

            Team t =null;
            try{
                t=(Team)q.getSingleResult();
            }
            catch(NoResultException e){
                return null;
            }
            players=t.getPlayers();

            result=new ArrayList<String>();

            for(Player p:players){
                result.add(p.getName());
            }   

            return result;
        }
       }
```

I have also the entity Player in jpa but i think its not important in this issue.

Now in the **jax-rs** "WS.java":

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.ejb.EJB;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import ejb.Player;

@Path("/projectws")
public class WS{

    @EJB
    Player ejbP;

    public WS() {
        System.out.println("WS created");
    }

    @GET
    @Path("getplayers")
    @Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
    public ArrayList<String> getPlayers() {


        ArrayList<String> ls;
        ls = ejbP.getFromTeam("teamA");

        System.out.println(ls.size());


        return ls;
    }
}
```

And I also have

```
package rest;

import javax.ws.rs.ApplicationPath;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Application;

@ApplicationPath("rest")
public class Test extends Application {
}
```

I already try a lot of things and nothing is working, do you see what can be wrong?

Whole stack trace:

```
Error processing request
Context Path:
/Project

Servlet Path:
/rest

Path Info:
/projectws/getplayers

Query String:
null

Stack Trace
org.jboss.resteasy.spi.UnhandledException: java.lang.NullPointerException
org.jboss.resteasy.core.ExceptionHandler.handleApplicationException(ExceptionHandler.java:77)
org.jboss.resteasy.core.ExceptionHandler.handleException(ExceptionHandler.java:220)
org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.writeException(SynchronousDispatcher.java:175)
org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:418)
org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:209)
org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ServletContainerDispatcher.service(ServletContainerDispatcher.java:221)
org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:56)
org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:51)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:85)
io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:131)
io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)
io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)
io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:60)
io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:77)
io.undertow.security.handlers.NotificationReceiverHandler.handleRequest(NotificationReceiverHandler.java:50)
io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:43)
io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:292)
io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$100(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:138)
io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:135)
io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:48)
io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:272)
io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:104)
io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:202)
io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:805)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I also have a warning:

```
20:51:22,035 WARNING [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.config] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 80) javax.naming.NamingException: WFLYNAM0027: Failed instantiate InitialContextFactory org.jboss.naming.remote.client.InitialContextFactory from classloader ModuleClassLoader for Module "deployment.proj-EAR.ear.proj-WEB.war:main" from Service Module Loader [Root exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jboss.naming.remote.client.InitialContextFactory from [Module "deployment.proj-EAR.ear.proj-WEB.war:main" from Service Module Loader]]: javax.naming.NamingException: WFLYNAM0027: Failed instantiate InitialContextFactory org.jboss.naming.remote.client.InitialContextFactory from classloader ModuleClassLoader for Module "deployment.proj-EAR.ear.proj-WEB.war:main" from Service Module Loader [Root exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jboss.naming.remote.client.InitialContextFactory from [Module "deployment.proj-EAR.ear.proj-WEB.war:main" from Service Module Loader]]
        at org.jboss.as.naming.InitialContext.getDefaultInitCtx(InitialContext.java:118)
        at org.jboss.as.naming.InitialContext.init(InitialContext.java:99)
        at javax.naming.ldap.InitialLdapContext.<init>(InitialLdapContext.java:154)
        at org.jboss.as.naming.InitialContext.<init>(InitialContext.java:89)
        at org.jboss.as.naming.InitialContextFactory.getInitialContext(InitialContextFactory.java:43)
        at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getInitialContext(NamingManager.java:684)
        at javax.naming.InitialContext.getDefaultInitCtx(InitialContext.java:313)
        at javax.naming.InitialContext.init(InitialContext.java:244)
        at javax.naming.InitialContext.<init>(InitialContext.java:192)
        at com.sun.faces.config.WebConfiguration.processJndiEntries(WebConfiguration.java:835)
        at com.sun.faces.config.WebConfiguration.<init>(WebConfiguration.java:155)
        at com.sun.faces.config.WebConfiguration.getInstance(WebConfiguration.java:216)
        at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextInitialized(ConfigureListener.java:166)
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.ApplicationListeners.contextInitialized(ApplicationListeners.java:187)
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl$1.call(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:200)
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl$1.call(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:171)
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:42)
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
        at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
        at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
        at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
        at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
        at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
        at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl.deploy(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:234)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService.startContext(UndertowDeploymentService.java:100)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService$1.run(UndertowDeploymentService.java:82)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
        at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:320)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jboss.naming.remote.client.InitialContextFactory from [Module "deployment.proj-EAR.ear.proj-WEB.war:main" from Service Module Loader]
        at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:198)
        at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:363)
        at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:351)
        at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:93)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
        at org.jboss.as.naming.InitialContext.getDefaultInitCtx(InitialContext.java:113)
        ... 32 more
```

In the wildfy log I can see that the error is in the line 30 that is "`ls = ejbP.getFromTeam("teamA");`" I just dont understand why is giving npe here

I try this and I get the same issue class not found exception. But like below I cant access "http://localhost:8080/rest/projectws/getplayers".

```
InitialContext ic=null;

CRUDStudentRemote bean=null; 


@GET
    @Path("getplayers")
    @Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
    public ArrayList<String> getPlayers() {

        try{
            ic=new InitialContext();

            bean = (PlayerRemote) 
                    ic.lookup("Projects/Player!ejb.PlayerRemote");

            ArrayList<String> ls;
            ls = bean.getFromTeam("teamA");

            System.out.println(ls.size());
            return ls;

        }
        catch(NamingException e){
            System.out.println("error.");
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(1);
        }


        return null;

    }
```

Comment: Is that your whole stack trace?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I update it now.

Comment: You are going to need to learn to use a debugger on your server.  You cannot debug a program by asking stackoverflow questions.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Im getting this errors above, I just dont understand why is happening because everything seems ok so I ask to see if someone can give a help. And i know what nep is.

Comment: I'd pay close attention to that `Caused by` section in the warning you're getting.  It sounds like you're missing a required class at runtime.  Not being able to instantiate something might be a cause for an NPE later.

Comment: You'll need to look in the server logs to see the cause of your NPE. The stack trace you posted is RESTEasy just catching the error and rethrowing it. You'll need the under underneath it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But in the wildfy log I can see that the error is in the line 30 that is "ls = ejbP.getFromTeam("teamA");" I just dont understand why is giving npe here.

Comment: `ejbP` is null. Invoking a method on a null instance causes `NullPointerException`. It is null because container could not inject `@EJB Player ejbP;` And this is probably caused by `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException org.jboss.naming.remote.client.InitialContextFactory`. The ContextFactory is responsible of looking for instances of EJBs

Answer (score 0):

`WS` class is not managed by the `EJB container` so it can not inject `Player ejbP`. You could either make the service an `EJB` ot you could aquire the `Player` instance thru the `InitialContext`.

Comment: Or use `CDI` injection or `provider SPI`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I try to do like I update in the question but the issue remains.